# How to package all files in msi

Tags: installshield

I have install shield 2013. I recently converted an existing msi file to a ism using [this](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=17743) article. I am a total noob w.r.t installshield but I'm on a tight deadline (needed to deploy on Friday... its now Sunday L.O.A.D (Life Of A Developer :) )). I built my ism project and now I have a msi file but I noticed my files are not packaged in the msi but on seperate folder.

How can I package the files into the msi.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project, select Project Assistant tab, Build Installation panel, select Single MSI Package checkbox, then click Build Installations button.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but just because I ran into this I'll let you know what worked for me without using the Project Assistant tab.

1. On the "Releases" screen, right-click the release you want to affect and run the "Release Wizard".
2. On the "Media Type" dialog, select "Network Image".
3. On the "Release Configuration" dialog, select "Compress all files".
4. When you get to the "Advanced Settings" dialog UNCHECK "Optimize size".

With those settings, you should get an MSI with no .cab files.  As a side note, the name of the .msi file will be whatever the Product Name property is set to in the General Information screen.